# VB.NET DataGridView End Edits and Cell Movment

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created a DGV adding CheckBoxColumns and TextBoxColumns. When the user enters a text value in to a TextBoxCell it then takes 2 mouse clicks to move to the next clicked cell, is there a way to allow a single mouse click to allow the next value to be entered in the selected cell straight away?

Also trying to use the Arrow Up/Down keys after entering a value doesn't move to the relevant new cell? When i use the arrow key is seems to end the edit but doesn't move to the next cell, it looks like the DGV loses focus as the mouse cursor appears.

I need both of these to work and to allow for immediate edit/ data entry as each text cell is for user input and not being able to use mouse keys to quickly navigate or having to double click with the mouse is causing a lot of wasted time.

Any help regarding these two issue would be much appreciated!

**Additional Info::**

This is what the grid looks like::

[Grid Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb9qL.png)

The first 2 columns are data populated from a previous form and the data is held in a DataTable, the rest of the columns are added via the program

With the 3 text columns it takes two clicks on the next cell to move to the requested cell and start to edit if something has been typed, again if something has been typed in a cell and i use the arrow keys doesn't seem to take you to the next cell, it leaves the cell put doesn't start to edit or put the cursor in the expected cell.

What i am looking for is when i have entered a value in to the Text Columns and click on the next cell it starts to edit straight away or if i use an arrow key it takes you to the relevant cell and starts the edit.

Below is the full code for the form i have an issue with, i have also added a screenshot of the DGV Properties as i bet all of this is fixed by something simple.

[DGV Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm7eU.jpg)

```
Public Class frmAppTest

Public DTApp As DataTable = New DataTable("Application")

Private Sub frmAppTest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Call InitializeAppTable()

    'Add each column required for user input (inc dropdown option and "Select All" option)
    Call Add_ChkColumn("Team Crest", "TEAM_CREST")
    Call AddSAChkBox(dgvApp, 186, 57, 2, "TC")
    Call AddCrestSelect(dgvApp, 165, 33, "Crest")
    Call Add_ChkColumn("Chest Logo", "CHEST_LOGO")
    Call AddSAChkBox(dgvApp, 246, 57, 3, "CL")
    Call AddSponsorSelect(dgvApp, 225, 33, "Chest")
    Call Add_ChkColumn("Back" & vbCr & "Top", "BACK_TOP_LOGO")
    Call AddSAChkBox(dgvApp, 306, 57, 4, "BT")
    Call AddSponsorSelect(dgvApp, 285, 33, "BackTop")
    Call Add_ChkColumn("Back Bottom", "BACK_BOTTOM_LOGO")
    Call AddSAChkBox(dgvApp, 366, 57, 5, "BB")
    Call AddSponsorSelect(dgvApp, 345, 33, "BackBottom")
    Call Add_ChkColumn("Left Sleeve", "LEFT_SLEEVE_LOGO")
    Call AddSAChkBox(dgvApp, 426, 57, 6, "LS")
    Call AddSponsorSelect(dgvApp, 405, 33, "LeftSlv")
    Call Add_ChkColumn("Right Sleeve", "RIGHT_SLEEVE_LOGO")
    Call AddSAChkBox(dgvApp, 486, 57, 7, "RS")
    Call AddSponsorSelect(dgvApp, 465, 33, "RightSlv")
    Call Add_TxtColumn("Player Name", "PLAYER_NAME")
    Call AddColourSelect(dgvApp, 528, 33, "Name")
    Call Add_TxtColumn("Player Number", "PLAYER_NUMBER")
    Call AddColourSelect(dgvApp, 638, 33, "Number")
    Call Add_TxtColumn("Player Initials", "PLAYER_INITIALS")
    Call AddColourSelect(dgvApp, 748, 33, "Initials")
    Call FormatDGVApp()

    'Populate default data
    Call PopulateDetails()

End Sub

Private Sub AddCrestSelect(ByVal theDataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal XLocation As Integer, ByVal YLocation As Integer, ByVal CboName As String)
    Dim cbo As New ComboBox
    cbo.Name = "cboLogo" & CboName
    'The box size
    cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    cbo.Visible = True
    cbo.Items.Clear()
    cbo.Items.Add("Embro")
    cbo.Items.Add("Heat")
    cbo.Size = New Size(55, 14)
    cbo.SelectedIndex = 0

    cbo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XLocation, YLocation)
    cbo.BackColor = Color.White
    theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbo)

End Sub

Private Sub AddSponsorSelect(ByVal theDataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal XLocation As Integer, ByVal YLocation As Integer, ByVal CboName As String)
    Dim cbo As New ComboBox
    cbo.Name = "cboLogo" & CboName
    'The box size
    cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    cbo.Visible = True
    cbo.Items.Clear()
    cbo.Items.Add("Single")
    cbo.Items.Add("Multi")
    cbo.Size = New Size(55, 14)
    cbo.SelectedIndex = 0

    cbo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XLocation, YLocation)
    cbo.BackColor = Color.White
    theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbo)

End Sub

Private Sub AddColourSelect(ByVal theDataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal XLocation As Integer, ByVal YLocation As Integer, ByVal CboName As String)
    Dim cbo As New ComboBox
    cbo.Name = "cboColour" & CboName
    'The box size
    cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    cbo.Visible = True
    cbo.Items.Clear()
    cbo.Items.Add("White")
    cbo.Items.Add("Black")
    cbo.Items.Add("Royal")
    cbo.Items.Add("Navy")
    cbo.Items.Add("Yellow")
    cbo.Items.Add("Red")
    cbo.Size = New Size(100, 14)
    cbo.SelectedIndex = 0

    cbo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XLocation, YLocation)
    cbo.BackColor = Color.White
    theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbo)

End Sub

Private Sub InitializeAppTable()

    DTApp.Columns.Add("Size", GetType(String))
    DTApp.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(String))
    dgvApp.DataSource = DTApp

End Sub

Private Sub FormatDGVApp()

    Dim xCol As New DataGridViewColumn

    dgvApp.Columns("Size").Width = 70
    dgvApp.Columns("Size").ReadOnly = True
    dgvApp.Columns("Size").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvApp.Columns("Size").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dgvApp.Columns("Size").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

    dgvApp.Columns("Price").Width = 70
    dgvApp.Columns("Price").ReadOnly = True
    dgvApp.Columns("Price").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvApp.Columns("Price").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dgvApp.Columns("Price").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

    dgvApp.ColumnHeadersHeight = 74

    dgvApp.Font = New Font("Arial", 7)

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateDetails()

    Dim AppRow As DataRow

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 4
        AppRow = DTApp.NewRow
        AppRow("Size") = "S"
        AppRow("Price") = "5.00"
        DTApp.Rows.Add(AppRow)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Add_ChkColumn(ByVal Header As String, ByVal Name As String)

    Dim AddColumnLabelExport As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

    With AddColumnLabelExport
        .HeaderText = Header
        .Name = Name
        .Width = 60
        .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter
        .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    End With

    dgvApp.Columns.Add(AddColumnLabelExport)

End Sub

Private _IsSelectAllChecked As Boolean

Private Sub AddSAChkBox(ByVal theDataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal XLocation As Integer, ByVal YLocation As Integer, ByVal TagNo As Integer, ByVal ChkName As String)
    Dim cbx As New CheckBox
    cbx.Name = "SelectAll" & ChkName
    'The box size
    cbx.Size = New Size(14, 14)
    cbx.Tag = TagNo

    cbx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XLocation, YLocation)
    cbx.BackColor = Color.White
    theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbx)

    AddHandler cbx.Click, AddressOf HeaderCheckBox_Click
   
    AddHandler theDataGridView.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CellChecked
    AddHandler theDataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

End Sub

Private Sub HeaderCheckBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Me._IsSelectAllChecked = True

    Dim cbx As CheckBox
    cbx = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim theDataGridView As DataGridView = cbx.Parent
    Dim rowId As Integer = cbx.Tag

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvApp.Rows
        row.Cells(rowId).Value = cbx.Checked
    Next

    theDataGridView.EndEdit()

    Me._IsSelectAllChecked = False
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView_CellChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    dgvApp.EndEdit()
    Dim dataGridView As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If Not Me._IsSelectAllChecked Then
        Select Case e.ColumnIndex
            Case 2
                If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = False Then
                    'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllTC"), CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
                    'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
                    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                        If row.Cells(2).Value = False Then
                            isAllChecked = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllTC"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
                End If
            Case 3
                If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = False Then
                    'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllCL"), CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
                    'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
                    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                        If row.Cells(3).Value = False Then
                            isAllChecked = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllCL"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
                End If
            Case 4
                If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value = False Then
                    'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllBT"), CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
                    'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
                    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                        If row.Cells(4).Value = False Then
                            isAllChecked = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllBT"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
                End If
            Case 5
                If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value = False Then
                    'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllBB"), CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
                    'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
                    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                        If row.Cells(5).Value = False Then
                            isAllChecked = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllBB"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
                End If
            Case 6
                If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Value = False Then
                    'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllLS"), CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
                    'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
                    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                        If row.Cells(6).Value = False Then
                            isAllChecked = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllLS"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
                End If
            Case 7
                If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value = False Then
                    'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllRS"), CheckBox).Checked = False
                Else
                    'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
                    'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
                    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                        If row.Cells(7).Value = False Then
                            isAllChecked = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAllRS"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
                End If
        End Select
    End If

    dgvApp.CurrentCell = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim dataGridView As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If TypeOf dataGridView.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
        dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Add_TxtColumn(ByVal Header As String, ByVal Name As String)

    Dim AddColumnLabelExport As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    With AddColumnLabelExport
        .HeaderText = Header
        .Name = Name
        .Width = 110
        .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter
        .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    End With

    dgvApp.Columns.Add(AddColumnLabelExport)

End Sub

Private Sub btnCancelLine_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancelLine.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is unclear what the grids `EditMode` might be. Have you tried setting the grids `EditMode` to `EditOnEnter`?

Comment: The DGV is already set to "EditOnEnter", thanks

Comment: Well, if you have the grids edit mode set to `EditOnEnter`, then I am not following what you are asking. I am not sure what you mean when you say… _”…then takes 2 mouse clicks to move to the next clicked cell, is there a way to allow a single mouse click to allow the next value to be entered in the selected cell straight away?”_ … In my small tests, if you “single” click into a cell then start typing, then, the cell goes into edit mode. I did not have to click “twice” to edit the cell.

Comment: In addition, you state that… _”When i use the arrow key is seems to end the edit but doesn't move to the next cell, … “_ … ? … again, I cannot reproduce this behavior you describe. The arrow keys work as expected and move to the next cell depending on “which” arrow key I pressed. Can you post some code that reproduces what you describe?... It will be difficult to suggest a solution if we can NOT reproduce the problems you describe.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for your reply, i have edited my initial post to include a screenshot of the form i am trying to fix, i have also include some code to show how the form is built and how i add the required columns. Any more information you might need that will help please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, using your posted code, I am still unable to reproduce the issues you describe. Only one click is required to start editing the cell. Also, the arrow keys work as expected and move to the next cell as expected. Are you using any key press events for the grid? It is true that in order to set a cell into “edit mode” using the mouse, requires two clicks, however, simply clicking once into a cell to get it highlighted then immediately start typing only requires one mouse click. You should post a [mre] that reproduces what you describe.

Comment: @JohnG Once again thanks for your reply, i have now added the full code for the form and the DGV Settings (in case it is something simple in those i have done to cause this issue) Hopefully this will replicate the issue and if not I will be lost at why mine is acting in the way it is. I have tried where i type in a cell click in another and start typing however nothing types in the clicked cell and the cursor isn't in the clicked cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well… the updated code explains numerous issues you may be having. The big picture is that you need to take a little more care when subscribing to some events. It is not difficult to create a problem if you do not take care in checking when and how often your subscribed to events are firing.

Example, in your current code you have the method…

```
Private Sub AddSAChkBox(ByVal theDataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal XLocation As Integer, ByVal YLocation As Integer, ByVal TagNo As Integer, ByVal ChkName As String)
    Dim cbx As New CheckBox
    cbx.Name = "SelectAll" & ChkName
    'The box size
    cbx.Size = New Size(14, 14)
    cbx.Tag = TagNo
    cbx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(XLocation, YLocation)
    cbx.BackColor = Color.White
    theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbx)
    AddHandler cbx.Click, AddressOf HeaderCheckBox_Click
    AddHandler theDataGridView.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CellChecked
    AddHandler theDataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
End Sub
```

This code drops a check box into the grid and is called six (6) times. Once for each of the “select all” Header check boxes. Is what is incorrect are the last two lines of code…

```
AddHandler theDataGridView.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CellChecked
AddHandler theDataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
```

This is odd because each time the method is called a NEW handler is added to the grid. In other words, the code is subscribing to the same GRID event’s six (6) times.

If you put a couple of debug statements at the beginning and the end of the events, you will see that the events will obligingly fire five more times than needed.

Bottom line… these GRID events only need to be subscribed to ONCE. I suggest moving the code to the Forms `Load` event or some method that is only called once.

Next, your current issue relates to the fact that when you type text into the other non-check box cells, the wired-up grid events are still firing and you really do not want this when editing those non-check box cells. So, a simple solution is to check and make sure that when those events fire… that we do nothing if the cell is not one of the check box cells in the grid.

Currently the code is using the grids `CellValueChanged` event and its `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. In the current cell dirty state changed event, the code simply “commits” the edit to the cell which in turn will fire the grids `CellValueChanged` event where the code checks the check box cells. As you note… the current cell dirty state changed event will fire BEFORE the actual cell value is changed and this is the purpose of the commit so we can immediately see the changes in the grid.

I suggest you use the grids, `CellContentClick` event instead of the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. This event will fire when the user clicks into a cell and starts to edit the cell. It will fire when the user clicks a check box cell and changes its value. We do not need to do anything other than check if the cell is a check box cell and commit the edit. If the cell is NOT a check box cell then do nothing. This event may look something like…

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If (dgvApp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex < 2 Or dgvApp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex > 7) Then
        Return
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine("DataGridView_CellContentClick <- Enter")
    dgvApp.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    Debug.WriteLine("DataGridView_CellContentClick -> Leave")
End Sub
```

This will work when the check boxes are changed and it will ignore the non-check box cells, however if the user is editing a non-check box cell, then the grids `CellValueChanged` event will still fire if the non-check box cells value changed.… So similar to the above code, we need to check in the grids `CellValueChanged` event to see which cell value changed. If it is NOT a check box cell that changed, then we do not want to do anything. Therefore you could add the same check using the `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` variables… in the grids `CellValueChanged` event… Something like…

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If (e.ColumnIndex < 2 Or e.ColumnIndex > 7) Then
        Return
    End If
     ….. ‘rest of code
```

Another issue which I wish I had a good answer for is that… if you call the `HeaderCheckBox_Click` event that fires when the user clicks one of the “select all” header check boxes, then you may note that… IF the user has clicked into a check box cell and changed its value, then this will make that cell the grids `CurrentCell` and for some reason, it will not change its value as expected. I was only able to code a workaround that simply changes the grids `CurrentCell` to some other cell, then sets it back after the code changes the check box cell values. The changes I made may look something like…

```
Private Sub HeaderCheckBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("HeaderCheckBox <- Enter")
    Dim curCellRowIndex = dgvApp.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim curCellColIndex = dgvApp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    dgvApp.CurrentCell = dgvApp.Rows(0).Cells(0)
    Dim cbx As CheckBox
    cbx = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim rowId As Integer = cbx.Tag
    RemoveHandler dgvApp.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CellValueChanged
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvApp.Rows
        row.Cells(rowId).Value = cbx.Checked
    Next
    AddHandler dgvApp.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CellValueChanged
    dgvApp.CurrentCell = dgvApp.Rows(curCellRowIndex).Cells(curCellColIndex)
    Debug.WriteLine("HeaderCheckBox -> Leave")
End Sub
```

You may note that just before the `For Each` loop is started through the grid rows, we remove the GRIDS `CellValueChanged` event to prevent it from firing. We do not want it to fire at this time since we are checking or unchecking all the check boxes, therefore no checking is needed to see if they are all checked or not checked.

In my tests, these changes allowed the non-check box cells to work as expected. I hope this makes sense and helps. You may want to consider simplifying this. Example, in each of the `Select/Case` sections the code is doing the same thing with a different column index. I suggest creating a simple method that checks if all the check boxes are checked in a given column and return true/false. And I hope you do not plan on any horizontal scrolling of the grid as this will create a lot of work for you to scroll the added combo boxes, labels and check boxes you added to the grid… just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks you so much and for such a detailed answer!! as you will guess this is the first time i have needed to add extra columns with slightly complex additions (Select All boxes and drop down boxes within the header) and your answer perfectly explained where i went wrong with bad logic and repeated handler calls.